# Dropbox_uploader - can't upload

Tags: linux, dropbox, dropbox-api

I've read a bunch of dropbox_uploader posts out there and can't get this going.. 
I've created the app and ran the script to install the uploader app (https://github.com/andreafabrizi/Dropbox-Uploader) on my linux server. I run the 'info' and it all seems to be the way it's supposed to be. However, whenever I upload a file, like:

```
/usr/bin/dropbox.sh -f /home/.dropbox_uploader upload "/home/mydomain/public_html/smallfile.zip" "/smallfile.zip"
```

.. it looks like it's uploading, after which I get:

```
FAILED An error occurred requesting /upload
```

What am I missing?
(As far as I know settings/permissions on the server are correct...)

Comment: What if you move `-f /home/.dropbox_uploader` after `upload`? Or all the way to the end of the command?

Comment: Thanks Josh Jolly.. I put it after upload and now all of a sudden it wanted me to start everything all over. That was the bad part of this. Now the good part: it DID actually do what it needed to do and it showed me where it could've gone wrong. The result is a huge mess, BUT it did upload the file the way I wanted to...

Comment: It looks like it's running in debug mode or something, because it shows everything. Not sure why... Running it with -q to make it quiet, wants me to configure the whole thing over again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several things were done to solve this, so I'll just share all of them here:

1. Permissions weren't set right when the application was installed. Files had to be set to 644, while they were 600 at the time of installation. Not sure why this happened, but this has to be fixed.
2. Unlinked installation, started all the way over and set permissions (during setup) to "f", because last time I had "a" and it didn't work. This had no impact whatsoever. In the process of getting this stuff to work, I unlinked and reinstalled several times, making sure that I have "f" permissions, just to avoid any unnecessary quirks.
3. I could get it to work on the command line in SSH logged in as root, but not as the user when I ran the script from a domain. It would constantly ask me for the setup information again, even though I had filled this all in. Fix for this: edit the .sh file and set the path to the configuration file in there. (making it 'hard', not variable) Now it didn't ask me for the information anymore, but gave me the '/upload' error.
4. Found out that I had to set permissions inside my server's control panel for running shell scripts to 'normal' instead of 'jailed' or 'disabled'. Apparently it was 'jailed'

Running the script (the way it was intended) is now a breeze and works flawlessly. I hope the info above will help people out that get stuck with this thing..

Comment: In my case, I could upload a very big file (100+ GB) but not another one (300GB+). The second one is failing every time, 4 times tried already. And I can upload smaller files.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I think it was because my token permissions didn't match what's on the dropbox account. Unlink and try again, but set permissions to "a" (App folder), not "f" (Full).

Answer (score 0):

took a while but found the config file at home/pi/.dropbox_uploader
this is the real config file...
now the key, secret and token are stored in this file

```
CONFIGFILE_VERSION=2.0
OAUTH_APP_KEY=xxxxxxxx
OAUTH_APP_SECRET=xxxxxxxxxxxx
OAUTH_REFRESH_TOKEN=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).